# Is Ubuntu 12.04 a Plug and Play OS in BIOS?

Tags: 12.04, bios

In Windows since lots of years back one should always enable plug and play OS in the BIOS.

In GNU/Linux you should disable this option back in the old days.

How is it nowadays, using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit for example?

Answer (score 0):

Linux is capable of doing the most hardware configuration via ACPI. You can handle this like you do for Windows, so enable PnP in BIOS.

Comment: *enable*, not *enaple* guy. (I know than that's typo) :D